# Facebook iOS SDK Demo App - URL Scheme won't work

Tags: ios, facebook

I entered my App-ID (DemoAppViewController.m - Line 25) in the FB Demo App and added the following URL-Scheme in the Info.plist:

URL Types -> Item 0 -> URL Schemes -> Item 0 -> fb125014xxxxxxxxx

But everytime I'm trying to login it will redirect me to Safari. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

did you enter your app-id like this to DemoAppViewController.m?

@"app-id"

Comment: Yes, I've entered it this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the Facebook app installed, then that is the way it is supposed to work. It will call up Safari to collect the user's login credentials. Then it will return back to the app, the result of that login attempt (success, failed, canceled).

You can set the tryFBAuth or trySafariAuth settings to NO to disable those, outside mechanisms, in which case a dialog will pop up to collect user email/password.

Comment: The bad thing with that is if you do have Facebook app installed, it will take you to the app to do the login and you'll need the URL scheme of your appId, else it will get stucked in the FB app

Comment: @herz Based on his question, it looks like he configures his app with the proper scheme so that the FB app will re-invoke his app properly. His question was about why Safari was invoked, despite his settings. I disabled the call to Safari in my app... I had to modify the FB supplied SDK code to do that.

It isn't entirely clear to me what he was expecting. Was the problem that it never returned back to the app from Safari?

Comment: Oh my bad didn't understand your answer at all, sorry. I think his problem is that Safari is always launched when he tries to login and he doesn't have the FB app installed for sure, and if he doesn't want that, so he will need to do what you said above.